# does this reference the pointer returned with "new"?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have created a `char* str_1` and have allocated 64 bytes to it.

Then I created another `char* str_2` and referenced it to the initial string.

```
char* str_1 = new char[64];

char* str_2 = str_1; // does it reference the object created with the new statement.
```

My question is, does `str_2` contain the reference to the allocated memory? In which case, could I do something like this?

```
char* str_1 = new char[64];
char* str_2 = str_1;

delete[] str_2;
```

Is calling `delete[] str_2` actually deleting the allocated memory? Or, is it causing a **memory leak**?

Comment: `new char[64]` does not allocate 64 bits, but `8 * 64` bits, i.e. 64 bytes. Note that because of the lack of clarity about ownership (in addition to the lack of automatic cleanup) in scenarios like this makes `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` or `std::vector<char>` the preferred option: You know which variable object owns the memory and you can still move the memory to another object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the declaration of the pointer `str_2`, both pointers `str_1` and `str_2` are pointing to the same dynamically allocated memory (character array).

```
char* str_1 = new char[64];
char* str_2 = str_1;
```

After calling the operator `delete []`:

```
delete[] str_2;
```

Both pointers become invalid, because they both do not point to an existing object.

There is no memory leak. You may use either pointer to delete the allocated array. But you may not delete the same dynamically allocated memory twice.

A memory leak occurs when a memory was allocated dynamically and was not freed at all.

Comment: key point here: you do not delete pointers - you delete the places they point to

Answer (score 3):

`str_1` and `str_2` are pointing to the same piece of allocated memory, so you could use either `str_1` or `str_2` to free that memory.

However, don't use both to free the memory, that would be a double delete. And don't use either pointer after you have freed the memory.